# AWS Signature: Canonical Request, what is the payload for POST application/json?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3

What's the payload for `POST application/json` request? There's no example for `POST application/json` on their [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html), and also I've look onto their [test suites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-test-suite.html), but their POST examples are only `form-url-encoded`.

Can anyone give an example of POST application/json (with body of course) with its hashed payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this question is not about AWS, I'm just dumb not to know that the payload was a term on API, and it was the **JSON body**.

Example:

Body (This is the payload):

```
{
   "first_name": "Tenten"
}
```

Just convert to JSON string and hash it. That's it.